# React context missing in Vite monorepo

Tags: reactjs, react-context, vite, tsc, lerna

I'm trying to switch my lerna monorepo over from create-react-app to vite. My repo structure is roughly:

```
- packages
  - shared
    - useSomeHook.ts
    - useSomeHook2.ts
  - app1
    - SomeConsumer.tsx
```

`useSomeHook` wraps a 3rd party hook (redux's `useSelector`) and returns some values. `useSelector` requires being called down the tree from a redux store context provider. I have Storybook setup with a redux decorator in the shared package and I verified that `useSomeHook` is working when used in the shared package. The issue is when I import and use `useSomeHook` in `SomeConsumer.tsx` in app1, the redux context is now undefined.

I am 100% absolutely certain that it is being called within the redux provider in app1. All of the bare calls of `useSelector` in app1 are working as intended, it's exclusively on this hook that I'm importing from my shared package.

I also have `useSomeHook2` that wraps a different 3rd party hook that also relies on context (react-router's `useHistory`) that's displaying the same problem. There was no issue when the shared package was bundled with `tsc`. I think the main difference is that `tsc` was outputting commonjs while vite is outputting esm, but I have no idea where to start debugging.

Comment: hey I'm not sure if that can help or not but I guess you can create the workspace first with pnpm workspaces take for example my [Vue 3 with pnpm workspace](https://github.com/ghiscoding/vue3-pnpm-workspace) boilerplate and then add Lerna after that. Also may I suggest [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/ghiscoding/lerna-lite) as a smaller alternative that I maintain, it also supports the [`workspace:`](https://pnpm.io/workspaces#workspace-protocol-workspace) protocol from pnpm, Lerna-Lite also uses it and it's prioritize local deps instead downloading from npm registry. I never used React btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was not using the `rollup.externals` array. The shared hooks where trying to consume a context from the shared package instead of where they were being called in app1. My understanding is that the externals array fixes this resolution

Comment: Hey, I have run into the same issue but im struggling to understand what to put in my rollup.externals array? could you give a snippet of whats in yours?

this is my setup and the error that im getting

```Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>```

apps/ app1 (consumes lib1)

libraries/lib1 (contains  rtkquery & redux code)

Comment: Sure, this would be what resolved it `rollupOptions: {external: ['react-redux', 'react-router', 'react-router-dom', 'redux']}` in the shared vite config