# building vite with redux library fails

Tags: reactjs, redux, vite

I am trying to build a vite application that has redux with react and it's giving me this error:

```
$ pnpm build

> temp-vite@1.0.0 build
> tsc && vite build

vite v4.3.9 building for production...
✓ 639 modules transformed.
✓ built in 1.67s
"createContext" is not exported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/index.js", imported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/react-redux@8.0.5_@types+react-dom@18.0.11_@types+react@18.0.37_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Context.js".
file: .pnpm/react-redux@8.0.5_@types+react-dom@18.0.11_@types+react@18.0.37_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Context.js:1:9
1: import { createContext } from 'react';
            ^
2: export const ReactReduxContext = /*#__PURE__*/createContext(null);
error during build:
RollupError: "createContext" is not exported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/react@18.2.0/node_modules/react/index.js", imported by "../../node_modules/.pnpm/react-redux@8.0.5_@types+react-dom@18.0.11_@types+react@18.0.37_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0_redux@4.2.1/node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Context.js".

ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me - adding the problem libraries in rollupOptions/external
[React context missing in Vite monorepo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159278/react-context-missing-in-vite-monorepo)
you may also try this - adding named exports
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1654